# Почему не работает middleware в laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Мне нужно сделать ограничение по ролям на проекте, но при использование двух ролей на одни ссылки через middleware доступа нет и у одной

Код web.api:

```
Route::middleware(['moder','admin'])->group(function() {
Route::post('/submit/add/author', 'BookController@submit2');
Route::post('/author/change/{id}', 'BookController@ChangeAuthor')->name('author-change-yes');
Route::get('/add/author', 'BookController@AllDataAuthor');
Route::get('/author/change', 'BookController@AllViewAuthorAd')->name('author-change-refresh');
Route::get('/author/change/{id}', 'BookController@ChangeOneAuthor')->name('author-change');

Route::get('/change', 'BookController@AllViewAd')->name('book-change-refresh');
Route::get('/change/{id}', 'BookController@ChangeOne')->name('book-change');
Route::get('/add', 'BookController@AllData');
Route::post('/change/{id}', 'BookController@Change')->name('book-change-yes');
Route::post('/submit/change', 'BookController@change');
Route::post('/submit/add', 'BookController@submit');
```

Код определения ролей

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)//админ
{
    $user= Auth::user();
    if($user->idRole==3){
        return $next($request);

    }
    return redirect(route('index'));
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)//модер
{
    $user= Auth::user();
    if($user->idRole==2){
        return $next($request);

    }
    return redirect(route('index'));
}
```

При использование только одного middleware срабатывает

Comment: Совместите в одну прокладку, назовите ModerOrAdmin, и проверяйте пользователя там аналогично.

Comment: @Daniel Спасибо, помогло